# Monitor in power saving mode while CPU is still running

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, lcd

I am have a problem with my LCD going into power saving mode. It all started about three days back by randomly going into power saving mode while PC is smoothly running. Then the frequency of going into power saving mode increased (No driver updates were carried out etc.). Then after two days LCD directly goes into power saving mode and not even a single display from CPU appears whereas CPU seems to be running fine (power supply, fan and LED on motherboard all working). However after this problem CPU does not respond to shutdown by pressing power button.

On a running CPU I unplugged VGA cable and LCD displayed the standard message of no signal. Then I unplugged and replaced the VGA cable and it displayed "Monitor in power saving mode" and a green LED on LCD shifted to amber. I checked LCD independently by connecting it to a laptop which led me to the conclusion that LCD and its cables are working.

Uptil now I have tried following solutions (from various forums):

1. Someone suggested that I take out and replace the bios battery from motherboard because it might have gone weak due to excessive use and might be forcing for power saving mode.
2. Removing RAM and restarting CPU to invoke it out of power saving mode.
3. Changed slots of RAM and rechecked all connections on motherboard.

All these things had no effect. Someone also suggested that power supply might not be able to provide enough power thereby forcing CPU to power saving mode. However I didn't pursue this option because I do not have an extra power supply. Additionally it had been working on same power supply for about a year. I am using internal graphics on the motherboard.

Comment: I'd probably try setting up RDP or VNC on the system when the monitor works, to see if its still responsive when the monitor powers off. And as always to take a look at event viewer to check for errors.

Comment: Did you tried connecting another monitor to the machine?

Comment: Another thing is that I earlier thought that this might be happening because Windows is experiencing some internal errors or some system programs are crashing. Therefore I set off the automatic restart from control pannel so that computer may intimate me before restarting. However not even a single error was reported.